# Playing sequential sounds from Array - AS3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, function, audio

I'm pretty new to flash and I couldnt figure this out:

I need some kind of function where you send an Array of urls ( ["sounds/cow.mp3","sounds/dog.mp3"] ) and then it loads and plays those sounds sequentially. When it is finished it should dispach a COMPLETE event.

can someone mock something up for me?

tnx in advance

dbre

Comment: http://www.quip.net/blog/2007/flash/how-to-play-sound-files-sequentially

Comment: @Ronnie this is as2...

Comment: Homework, maybe? I suggest you read up on the Sound and SoundChannel classes, as well as the URLLoader class. Should give you a good start

Comment: thanks @stalem SoundChannel was what I was searching for.